# React Hook Form - manually update some fields in pre-registered object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working on multi-tabs form, and I've faced issue with updating only some keys from current context.

Example:

In default values I have 3 keys:

```
{
  key1: 'A',
  key2: 'B',
  key3: [
    {
      nested1: 'N1_1',
      nested2: 'N2_1',
    },
    {
      nested1: 'N1_2',
      nested2: 'N2_2',
    }
  ],
}
```

And I've used useFieldArray for key3, but I want to have ability to change only 1 key from each object and rest should be populated from current context. But there is no option to do that - everything which is not rendered, will be lost.
There is the second option - we can manually register key3. But then there is no possible to update anything from this array.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-nested-fields-from-default-5nlop?file=/src/index.js

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: each useFieldArray have it's own scope, for update child field array, you will probably need to leverage useEffect.